# Filtering two lists simultaneously

Tags: python, filtering

I have three lists:

```
del_ids = [2, 4]
ids = [3, 2, 4, 1]
other = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

and my goal is to remove `del_ids` with the result being

```
ids = [3, 1]
other = ['a', 'd']
```

I have tried to do a mask for elements to keep (`mask = [id not in del_ids for id in ids]`) and I plan to apply this mask on both lists.

But I feel that this is not a pythonic solution. Can you please tell me how I can do this better?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

zip, filter and unzip again:

```
ids, other = zip(*((id, other) for id, other in zip(ids, other) if id not in del_ids))
```

The `zip()` call pairs each `id` with the corresponding `other` element, the generator expression filters out any pair where the `id` is listed in `del_ids`, and the `zip(*..)` then teases out the remaining pairs into separate lists again.

Demo:

```
>>> del_ids = [2, 4]
>>> ids = [3, 2, 4, 1]
>>> other = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
>>> zip(*((id, other) for id, other in zip(ids, other) if id not in del_ids))
[(3, 1), ('a', 'd')]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, can you please tell me what the star is for, in this situation? That form of for comprehension is new to me. :O

Comment: @BarnabasSzabolcs: It applies the sequence (all the pairs from the generator expression) as separate arguments to the `zip()` function. `zip()` sees `zip(pair1, pair2, pair3, etc.)`, then zips all those pairs into two lists.

Comment: @BarnabasSzabolcs: The `(.. for .. in ..)` construct is a generator expression. It is a lot like a list comprehension (`[.. for .. in ..]`) except it doesn't build a new list in memory first.

Comment: aaah, I see, thanks! I'll accept the answer once I have the permission.

Comment: Wow, really? It looks like I will be able to remember and use that in a couple of years...

Comment: Valid answer (+1), but inefficient use of space and time. The search through `del_ids` takes O(len(del_ids)) time for each search operation (or linear runtime for all filtering if you were to setify `del_ids`), which could get expensive. Then there's the zipping and unzipping which really shouldn't absolutely need to be done. [Why not just pop the indices in reverse sorted order from `other`?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17996588/198633)

Comment: @inspectorG4dget: The linear search through `del_ids` can be mitigated by using a set instead. In Python 2, `itertools.izip()` can be used instead, Python 3's `zip()` already is an iterator.

Comment: Wouldn't creating a `dict` out of `ids` and `other` be a better solution here?

Comment: @ersran9: Sure, I can think of better data structures too. But perhaps order is important (answer: use `OrderedDict`), perhaps duplicates should be allowed (then use a sequence of tuples), etc.

Answer (score 2):

zip, filter, unzip :

```
ids, other = zip(*filter(lambda (id,_): not id in del_ids, zip(ids, other)))
```

Comment: @Martijn: filter return a filtered list of exactly 2 tuples, so I can safetely unpack them. Damn you are right, I made the correction.

Comment: Yes, until your filter returns more or fewer than 2 tuples. Don't go copy my solution with a subtle change until you understand what it does. :-P

Comment: @MartijnPieters: I actually wrote the answer before looking at yours. I guess great minds thinks alike ;-P

Answer (score 2):

In order to avoid learning tricky syntax, do it in two steps.

```
other = [o for my_id, o in zip(ids, other) if my_id not in del_ids]
ids = [my_id for my_id in ids if my_id not in del_ids]
```

*Drawback*
You must execute the statements in correct order, so there's risk of bugs if for some reason the order changes.

*Advantage*
It's straight forward, so you don't have to search Stackoverflow next time you want to do it.

Comment: I like your approach because it is clean.

Comment: Also, I wish `id` wasn't a reserved word in python... since id's would be such a common variable name. Having `i` confuses me because `i` usually refers to an integer looping index, not an id. Why didn't they have `__id__()` instead of `id()` if it is an implementation detail of python anyway?
So, now which is worst, having a misnamed variable or having a variable shadowing a builtin? Martijn seems to think the former is worse.

Comment: Thanks Barney, I changed the variable name.

Answer (score 1):

Converting to pandas data frame and applying the mask:

```
del_ids = [2, 4]
ids = [3, 2, 4, 1]
other = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
df = pd.DataFrame({'ids':ids,'other':other})
df = df[~df.ids.isin(del_ids)]
ids = df['ids'].tolist()
other = df['other'].tolist()
```